# Explicit value for identity column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Created a database in Visual Studio 2013 and primary key properties increment option true but still problem

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot insert explicit value for identity
>   column in table 'Patient' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Code:

```
con.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Patient (PId, FirstName, LastName, ContactNumber, Address, Gender, PatientRecord) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "') ",con); 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close(); 

MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully");
```

Comment: Post your insert query

Comment: con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Patient (PId,FirstName,LastName,ContactNumber,Address,Gender,PatientRecord) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "') ",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Save Successfully !!!!!!!!!");

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that has to be cause you are including the `Identity` column in `INSERT` statement. remove the identity column from your query statement like

```
INSERT INTO Patient (FirstName,LastName,ContactNumber,Address,Gender,PatientRecord) VALUES
```

Again, don't run query with concatenated data from your controls like Textbox cause that's vulnerable to `SQL Injection`. Rather consider using a parameterized query using `SqlParameter`. See MSDN for more information.

Comment: @Umer, Welcome and consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: i created form 1 page in window form application . 
now i create form 2 page and run form 2 page but show form 1 page.